# Filter Data in Oracle Goldengate Replicat Side

Tags: oracle-golden-gate

I have a requirement to setup CDC from Source(Oracle) to Target(BigQuery) using Goldengate.
I can have only option to filter data in replicat side based on Specific column name .
As per the below link :
https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/goldengate-cloud/gwuad/using-oracle-goldengate-parameter-files.html#GUID-7F405A81-B2D1-4072-B254-DC2B0EC56FBA

## I have setup the replicat like below

```
REPLICAT RPOC
TARGETDB LIBFILE libggjava.so SET property=dirprm/bqpoc.props
SOURCEDEFS /app/oracle/ogg_bigdata/dirdef/poc.def
REPORTCOUNT EVERY 1 MINUTES, RATE
GROUPTRANSOPS 500

MAP ARADMINPI.TPOC, TARGET PRD.TPOCFL,KEYCOLS(ID),WHERE (NAME= ?SOUVIKPOC);
```

===================================

## export SOUVIKPOC='Smith'

But I am getting below error

```
2020-02-19 05:47:37  ERROR   OGG-01157  Error in WHERE clause for ARADMINPI.TPOC.
```

=============================

Is there anything I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

For Parameter Substitution to work, you'll need to enclose `?SOUVIKPOC` in quotes, like this:

```
MAP ARADMINPI.TPOC, TARGET PRD.TPOCFL,KEYCOLS(ID),WHERE (NAME= '?SOUVIKPOC');
```

There should also be additional information about the failure earlier in the report file.

#### Another Example Using `@GETENV`

Another option is to use the `@GETENV` function instead of Parameter Substitution.  Here, the `MAP` statement uses a `FILTER` clause instead of the `WHERE` clause:

```
MAP ARADMINPI.TPOC, TARGET PRD.TPOCFL,KEYCOLS(ID),
    FILTER (@STREQ(NAME, @GETENV('OSVARIABLE', 'SOUVIKPOC')));
```

Unless you set the `SOUVIKPOC` environment variable prior to running `GGSCI` (and executing `START MGR`), you need to add a `SETENV` statement to your parameter file:

```
SETENV (SOUVIKPOC = 'Smith')
```

Putting it all together:

```
REPLICAT RPOC
TARGETDB LIBFILE libggjava.so SET property=dirprm/bqpoc.props
SOURCEDEFS /app/oracle/ogg_bigdata/dirdef/poc.def
REPORTCOUNT EVERY 1 MINUTES, RATE
GROUPTRANSOPS 500

SETENV (SOUVIKPOC = 'Smith')
MAP ARADMINPI.TPOC, TARGET PRD.TPOCFL,KEYCOLS(ID),
    FILTER (@STREQ(NAME, @GETENV('OSVARIABLE', 'SOUVIKPOC')));
```